# How to create Data Frames and call them using an array and for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

My question is the following:

I am trying to create a for loop to divide a single Data Set in 6 datasets (one per continent) using the names of the continents that are in the first df column 'continent'

So first I take the name of the continents and store them in an array:

```
continent = df['continent'].unique()
```

The I create the for loop (I would like each Dataset is called as one continent and have only the rows involving this continent):

```
for x in continent : 
    x = pd.DataFrame()
    x = df.loc[df["continent"]==x]
```

Could anybody help me on this topic?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `groupby`, notice we store all the dfs in `dict`, you can get the single df by `d['continent name']`

```
d={ x : y for x , y in df.groupby('continent')}
```